# On deleting the last record on page 2, navigate user back to page 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'm using Kaminari Gem on my rails apps.

I have the current index page with proper navigation menus.

```
def index
  @dogs = Dog.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)
end


def destroy
  if @dog.destroy
    # use this so that if the page got other records, the user got to stay at that navigated page.
    redirect_back fallback_location: dogs_path, flash: { success: 'deleted dog from list' }
  else
    # show some errors
  end
end
```

When user is at page 2 and deleting the 21st dog record, the record got deleted and the browser is showing a blank page with no record cause the url is specifying `/dogs?page=2`.

Is this the default behavior or Kaminari or I have something wrong on my method? I was expecting Kaminari to redirect the user to 1 page before since current page is not containing any records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have dogs index page path as `dogs_path`

```
def destroy
  if @dog.destroy
    page = params[:page]
    #this is to check if we have more elements on the page or not
    @dogs = Dog.all.page(page).per(20)
    if @dogs.length == 0 
      page = (page - 1) > 1 ? page - 1 : 1  
    end
    redirect_to dogs_path(page: page)
  else
    # show some errors
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is closest to what I wanted the behavior to be. Wonder why Kaminari Gem doesn't do this for us out of the library. Might be because it need another query to the database before redirect...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the index URL after the delete operation done. I am sure you have done the below.

`redirect_to :back` and it remains on the same page.

Instead of back, You should use the index page URL.

Comment: I want the user to remain on the same page pagination when there are still records on that particular page. For example, imagine navigate to 25th page and delete the first record on that page. Then the user got redirect back to the 1st page and he have to navigate 25 pages again to delete the other records.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Rails 5, you can now use `redirect_back(the_path_that_you_want)`
Im thinking on doing it this way, but still redirect to the same page when empty. Hmm..

```
def delete
  ...
  prev_page = Dogs.page(params[:page]).per(20).count < 1 ? params[:page].to_i - 1 : params[:page]
  redirect_back(fallback_location: dogs_path(page: prev_page, notice: "...", anchor: "if_you_wanted_to"))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use request.referer below is sample for destroy, first you save the referer with session[:return_to] = request.referrer, then after destroy you return back to previous page with redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)

```
def destroy
  session[:return_to] = request.referrer
  ....
  @dog.destroy
  if session[:return_to]
    redirect_to session.delete(:return_to)
  else
    redirect_to dogs_path
  end 
end
```